# Add prefix with distinct in group_concat sql

Tags: mysql, group-concat, sql-server-group-concat

Hey I have this query

```
select group_concat(distinct(accountId) separator "' ,") 
from xxx_yyy_replacement_instances
where deletedAt IS NULL
```

which returns me the next results

```
act-fdf4caf8' ,act-525d62af' ,act-e141e6ab' ,act-73995962' ,act-c782e06d' ,act-993aaec0' ,act-1a2f883e' ,act-ed6f5f9e
```

I want add `"'"` before each accountId

I used concat inside but then it can't get the distinct(accountId),
I used also

```
select group_concat(",",distinct(accountId) separator "' ,") 
from gcp_gce_replacement_instances
where deletedAt IS NULL
```

But I get an error with it.

The desired result is :`'act-fdf4caf8','act-525d62af','act-e141e6ab','act-73995962','act-c782e06d','act-993aaec0','act-1a2f883e','act-ed6f5f9e'`

Comment: `CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column SEPARATOR "','"), "'")`

Comment: Thanks, do you know about a solution with prefix ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the second `'` in the `SEPARATOR`, concatenate both of them with the account ID.

You don't need to call `CONCAT()` explicitly. You can put multiple values in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` arguments and they'll be concatenated.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "'", accountId, "'" SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM gcp_gce_replacement_instances
WHERE deletedAt IS NULL
```